# Laravel 4 how can I get the original password?

Tags: laravel-4

I use the Hash::make to deal with the password when it write into database.
But now I have a problem,How I get the original password? 
I mean not hashed password.
Because I have a page want to show the password to the user himself.
Should I have another database field to record the original password?
Or there has a simple Laravel way?

Comment: once it is hashed, you shouldn't be able to get the password back from the hash. They are one way.  Storing the password in a plain text extra field defeats the purpose of hashing it in the first place.  There should never be a need to show a user their password.  If they can't remember it, let them validate their account and offer to reset it for them, much safer

Comment: @Doon: That's an answer. And it's the *right* answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to expand on what Doon says, which as Mike points out is definitely correct - never save plain text passwords - always provide a reset option only for lost/forgotten passwords.

Laravel luckily can help you out here with its RemindableInterface, which you can implement in your User class/model, eg.

```
class User extends Eloquent implements RemindableInterface {

    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

}
```

so no need to start from scratch on this  - details about usage here - http://four.laravel.com/docs/security#password-reminders-and-reset

Glen